# Automorphisms of Abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a free Abelian group and $N$ a characteristic subgroup of $A$ such that $A/N$ is finite. I also know that $Aut(A/N)$ and $Aut(N)$ are both finite. *I have to prove* that $Aut(A)$ is finite.
Obviously $Hom(A/N,\, N)$ is finite (it is trivial).

I was trying to make a map from $Aut(A)$ into $Aut(A/N)\times Aut(N)\times Hom(A/N,\, N)$.
The first two components are pretty clear but the last one is more difficult. 
I thought that $\alpha\in Aut(A)\mapsto (\dots,\, \dots,\, \beta)$ where $\beta: A/N\rightarrow A$ is such that $\beta(a)=\alpha(a)\overline{\alpha(a)}^{-1}$, where the overline stands for some rappresentative, but it seems to me that the map does not work because we do not have a set of transversals such that the sum of two of them is still a transversal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your approach does not quite work. What you should do is to look at the kernel $K$ of the homomorphism ${\rm Aut}(A) \to {\rm Aut}(A/N) \times {\rm Aut}(N)$ and show that $K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Hom}(A/N,N)$.

Comment: Now I see! Thanks Derek!